# Getting timezone from 2d geospatial indexes in Mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, geolocation, timezone, geospatial

We have a 'places' collection with 2d geospatial indexes (loc), that specify the coordinates of places around the globe.

Can mongoDB be used to find the timezone for a given set of coordinates?
If not, what is a good practice to approach this topic?

Thanks you.

Comment: @MattJohnson Does this mean that there is no built-in / extension solution for mongo, without involving code?

Comment: That's correct.  You may also want to read [this mongodb-specific article](http://derickrethans.nl/what-time-is-it.html), which is also linked in that dup post.